# Asynchronous file writing possible in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aio-write

Is there an easy way write to a file asynchronously in Python?

I know the [file io that comes with Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is blocking; which is fine in most cases.  For this particular case, I need writes not to block the application at all, or at least as minimally as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twisted has [non-blocking writes on file descriptors](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.fdesc.html).  If you're writing async code, I'd expect you to be using twisted, anyway.  :)

Comment: Sadly, O_NONBLOCK (which is what the fdesc API you link to really does) does not work with local hard-disk files. i.e., the POSIX spec says that it should be ignored and it is dutifully ignored on every UNIX system I know of. If you think that this is a stupid idea, I could not agree more but there are a lot of historical and implementation reasons why this is so. In short, if you want asynchronous IO to local hard disk files, you better use threads and defer IO to an IO thread or use the AIO API.

Answer (score 19):

As I understand things, asynchronous I/O is not quite the same as non-blocking I/O.

In the case of non-blocking I/O, once a file descriptor is setup to be "non-blocking", a `read()` system call (for instance) will return `EWOULDBLOCK` (or `EAGAIN`) if the read operation would block the calling process in order to complete the operation. The system calls `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`, etc. are provided so that the process can ask the OS to be told when one or more file descriptors become *available* for performing some I/O operation.

Asynchronous I/O operates by queuing a request for I/O to the file descriptor, tracked independently of the calling process. For a file descriptor that supports asynchronous I/O (raw disk devcies typically), a process can call `aio_read()` (for instance) to request a number of bytes be read from the file descriptor. The system call returns immediately, whether or not the I/O has completed. Some time later, the process then polls the operating system for the *completion* of the I/O (that is, buffer is filled with data).

A process (single-threaded) that only performs non-blocking I/O will be able to read or write from one file descriptor that is ready for I/O when another is not ready. But the process must still synchronously issue the system calls to perform the I/O to all the ready file descriptors. Whereas, in the asynchronous I/O case, the process is just checking for the completion of the I/O (buffer filled with data). With asynchronous I/O, the OS has the freedom to operate in parallel as much as possible to service the I/O, if it so chooses.

With that, are there any wrappers for the POSIX aio_read/write etc. system calls for Python?

Comment: One thing to add: As the commenter on the first response says, no systems actually follow O_NONBLOCK on files — it's really for sockets only. If you want portable async file IO on Unix, you have to use POSIX AIO or offload your synchronous IO to a threadpool.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `Thread`:

```
from threading import Thread

for file in list_file:
     tr = Thread(target=file.write, args=(data,))
     tr.start()
```

This is more or less a pseudocode, but i hope you'd get the idea. Be aware the threads here are left open.

In my experience it worked well, although interpreter continue to work some time while the main script have finished (need to use `join()`), so the speed gain is so big than it seems

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing aio.h bidings to python: [pyaio](https://github.com/felipecruz/pyaio)

It runs on linux only..

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 seems to have such functionality. See [PEP 3116](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/).

Comment: Looks like PEP 3116 is related to a new I/O abstraction that includes non-blocking I/O. However, non-blocking I/O is not the same as asynchronous I/O. Non-blocking I/O generally doesn't apply to local filesystem writes.