# How to write to a file using non blocking IO?

Tags: python, file-io, nonblocking

I want to write to a file using a non-blocking method in Python. On some googling, I found that the language supports `fcntl` in order to do so, but the method to implement the same is not very clear to me.

This is the code snippet (I don't know where I am going wrong):

```
import os, fcntl
nf = fcntl.fcntl(0,fcntl.F_UNCLK)
fcntl.fcntl(0,fcntl.F_SETFL , nf | os.O_NONBLOCK )
nf = open ("test.txt", 'a') 
nf.write ( " sample text \n")
```

Is this the correct way to perform a non-blocking IO operation on a file? I doubt it. Also, could you suggest any other modules in Python which allow me to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous file writing possible in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319132/asynchronous-file-writing-possible-in-python)

Comment: No its not , i need to keep it simple by just using fcntl :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how you turn non-blocking mode on for a file in UNIX:

```
fd = os.open("filename", os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
os.write(fd, "data")
os.close(fd)
```

On UNIX, however, [turning on non-blocking mode has no visible effect for regular files](http://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml)! Even though the file is in non-blocking mode, the `os.write` call won't return immediately, it will sleep until the write is complete. To prove it to yourself experimentally, try this:

```
import os
import datetime

data = "\n".join("testing\n" * 10 for x in xrange(10000000))
print("Size of data is %d bytes" % len(data))

print("open at %s" % str(datetime.datetime.now()))
fd = os.open("filename", os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
print("write at %s" % str(datetime.datetime.now()))
os.write(fd, data)
print("close at %s" % str(datetime.datetime.now()))
os.close(fd)
print("end at %s" % str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

You'll notice that the `os.write` call does take several seconds. Even though the call is non-blocking (technically, it's not blocking, it's sleeping), the call is *not* asynchronous.

---

AFAIK, there is no way to write to a file asynchronously on Linux or on Windows. You can simulate it, however, using threads. Twisted has a method named `deferToThread` for this purpose. Here's how you use it:

```
from twisted.internet import threads, reactor

data = "\n".join("testing\n" * 10 for x in xrange(10000000))
print("Size of data is %d bytes" % len(data))

def blocking_write():
    print("Starting blocking_write")
    f = open("testing", "w")
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
    print("End of blocking_write")

def test_callback():
    print("Running test_callback, just for kicks")

d = threads.deferToThread(blocking_code)
reactor.callWhenRunning(cc)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: How would I gain access to the reactor object from within a LineReciver or other such protocol built by a server factory?

Comment: A non-blocking write can be done to a regular file with POSIX AIO or Windows IOCP.

Answer (score 4):

Writes are cached by the OS and dumped to disk after a few seconds. That is, they are "not blocking" already. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: What if the file is actually mounted on a network share? Surely, the call would only return after the acknowledgements have been received?

Comment: Depends of the remote file system and semantic implemented, synchronous or asynchronous. There are examples of both, or even things like "sync on close".