# Does asyncio supports asynchronous I/O for file operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.5

Does asyncio supports asynchronous I/O for file operations? If yes, how I can use this in Python 3.5 with async/await syntax code?

Comment: I mean, i need non-blocking file I/O functionality. But in docs i found only descriptors monitoring functions.

Comment: If you just want non-blocking IO you should just be able to use python's threads. Do you want async IO or non-blocking IO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319132/asynchronous-file-writing-possible-in-python might have some useful info.

Comment: Let's explain. I have several Tasks in my IOLoop, that are working with sockets. And I want to add one more Task, that will read data to send from a file. Synchronization will be performed by asyncio.Queue.

Answer (score 41):

Most operating systems don't support asynchronous file operations.
That's why `asyncio` doesn't support them either.

See [the asyncio wiki](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem) for further explanation.

Comment: It is. Even `node.js` uses thread pool internally for providing async file API

Comment: You mean they do support it?

Comment: They *emulate* it, it makes a difference.

Comment: It is not achieved cooperatively, so it suffers from having to to code around pre-emptive context switches, so more inefficient all in all?

Comment: It uses thread pool internally, not cooperative switch.  Performance is quite good though.

Comment: This is wildly wrong. Windows supports asynchronous file I/O via the OVERLAPPED flag (with the notable exception of opening files). libuv uses this.

Comment: @AntonLahti Windows is "wildly" different from most other OS. Can you name any others that do support this?  Note the answer states *most* don't support it.

Comment: I wonder if there is any more recent information than from more than 6 years ago (the article literally mentions "Recent discussion on the Linux Kernel: Non-blocking buffered file read operations (__September 2014__)." as the last point of reference). I highly doubt there hasn't been any change in that time.

Comment: Nothing is changed AFAIK, sorry.

Comment: file descriptor (Unix/Linux) is stateful for example if you seek (to relative position) then read, and seek (to relative position) then read the results of read depends on position which is not what you expected. To implement asyncio on files there is special/different kernel routines called [kernel aio](https://kkourt.io/blog/2017/10-14-linux-aio.html)

Comment: Even if the OS implementation isn't asynchronous, blocking the asyncio event loop may be undesirable.

Comment: Not true anymore since linux has `io_uring` and windows always had async file io.

Comment: most meaning "windows does but i don't care?"

Comment: @ErikAronesty most meaning most. If the OS that the vast majority of Python code is running on, much less the vast majority of Python code that cares about this level of performance in the first place, does not support async IO, then there's less of a case to implement it.

Comment: @Kye According to W3Techs, as of January 2023, 45.9% of all Python code runs on Windows.   So... basically IDGAF about windows... for no reason.

Answer (score 31):

That depends on what library you use.

### curio

`curio` offers this functionality, see https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#module-curio.file

### asyncio

Update 2021: `aiofile ~2` and `~3` (current) supports true asynchronous IO on `Linux >= 4.18` via https://github.com/mosquito/caio and falls back to threaded implementations otherwise.

Plain `asyncio` doesn't, although there are 3rd party libraries, e.g. `aiofiles` (where synchronous file access is isolated in threads) and `aiofile` (note the spelling) (where synchronous file access is in threads in other circumstances than the above paragraph)

Modern operating systems do provide asynchronous file primitives, but these are varied, thus each would need own implementation. Please compare:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html

I suspect someone will soon rip out underlying async io from `node.js` and make a decent Python library, or perhaps someone already has.

Specifically for Linux, there are low-level bindings in https://pypi.org/project/liburing/

For a solid overview of asynchronous IO APIs in Linux, circa 2020, see https://www.scylladb.com/2020/05/05/how-io_uring-and-ebpf-will-revolutionize-programming-in-linux/

Comment: As far as I know, all options that you've mentioned use threads (curio, aiofiles, glib's aio implementation, and even Windows Overlapped I/O uses a thread pool under the hood).

Comment: Is there a recommendation? aiofiles as suggested by the official python asyncio docs?

Comment: For `curio`, the canonical recommendation is `curio.file`; There doesn't seem to be a recommendation for `asyncio`, so pick whatever's popular, like `aiofiles`.

Comment: Apparently, ``aiofile`` (not ``aiofiles``!) supports [Linux libaio asynchronous file operations since version 2.0](https://pypi.org/project/aiofile/).

Comment: Cheers, @MisterMiyagi I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 14):

asyncio does not have support for this. However,  [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/) supports just this. Please have a look.

Comment: supporting it via threads is kinda janky, rather than using the native o/s aio stuff

Answer (score 5):

As per Python 3.9 this is possible to do with asyncio.
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread

```
await asyncio.to_thread(shutil.copyfile, "a", "b")
```

Comment: that's a blocking call executed in a separate thread. not async/await per se