# Threads or asyncio gather?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Which is the best method to do concurrent i/o operations?

- thread or
- asyncio

There will be list of files.

I open the files and generate a graph using the `.txt` file and store it on the disk.

I have tried using threads but its time consuming and sometimes it does not generate a graph for some files.

Is there any other method?

I tried with the code below with async on the `load_instantel_ascii` function but it gives exception

```
 for fl in self.finallist:
   k = randint(0, 9)
 try:

 task2.append( * [load_instantel_ascii(fleName = fl, columns = None,
   out = self.outdir,
   separator = ',')])

 except:
   print("Error on Graph Generation")

 event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(yl1
     for kl1 in task2)

 )
```

Comment: Reformat your code.  Your 20 character indentation is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything correct and you want asynchronous file I/O, then `asyncio` itself [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701824/1113207) it out of the box. In the end all asyncio-related stuff that provides [async file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42063265/1113207) does it using threads pool.

But it probably doesn't mean you shouldn't use `asyncio`: this lib is cool as a way to write asynchronous code in a first place, even if it wrapper above threads. I would give a try to something like [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles).