# Is there any python async file handler?

Tags: python, file, asynchronous, io

I am currently relying on `asyncio.to_thread` for running blocking code, such as file handling.

Is there any better way of doing this?

P.S `aiofile` doesn't seem to be doing any better either.

L.E

To provide what I'm currently testing:

```
import asyncio
import uvloop
import time
from pathlib import Path


async def aio(i):
    path = Path(f'io_test/async/{i}')
    await asyncio.to_thread(path.mkdir, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with await asyncio.to_thread(open, f'{path}/f.py', 'w') as f:
        await asyncio.to_thread(f.write, "print('Hello World!')")


def io(i):
    path = Path(f'io_test/blocking/{i}')
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(f'{path}/f.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write("print('Hello World!')")


async def async_main(n):
    ts = time.time()
    coroutines = [aio(i) for i in range(n)]
    await asyncio.gather(
        *coroutines
    )
    te = time.time()
    delta = te - ts
    print(f'ASYNC IO | Took {delta} seconds.')


def main(n):
    ts = time.time()
    [io(i) for i in range(n)]
    te = time.time()
    delta = te - ts
    print(f'BLOCKING IO | Took {delta} seconds.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvloop.install()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    tasks = 1000
    # async test
    asyncio.run(async_main(tasks))
    # blocking test
    main(tasks)
```

Expectedly or not, the "blocking" procedure is quite faster (2x even 3x).
The reason I can't just go without async is that I can't really afford having blocking points in my flow.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example and explain the issue you are having with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does asyncio supports asynchronous I/O for file operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699948/does-asyncio-supports-asynchronous-i-o-for-file-operations)

Comment: The TLDR is: The problem is the OS, not the library. ``aiofile`` (not ``aiofiles``) *does* use ``libaio`` if available.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, that answers my question. Thank you!