# Issue when performing non-block writing

Tags: python, file, asynchronous, io, nonblocking

I wrote the following code to understand how nonblocking write is operated:

```
import os, time

def takeAnap():
    print('I am sleeping a bit while it is writing!')
    time.sleep(50)

fd = os.open('t.txt', os.O_CREAT | os.O_NONBLOCK)
for i in range(100):
    # Non-blocking write
    fd = os.open('t.txt', os.O_APPEND | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    os.write(fd, str(i))
    os.close(fd)
    time.sleep(2)
takeAnap()
```

As you can see, I am creating `takeAnap()` to be activated while the loop is being processed so that I can convince my self that the writing is performed without blocking! However, the loop still blocks and the method is not performed until finishing. I am not sure if my understanding is wrong but as far as I know, non-blocking operation allows you to do other tasks while the writing is being processed. Is that correct? If so, kindly where is the problem in my code!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the `O_NONBLOCK` flag is used for. Here's what the flag *actually* does:

> This prevents open from blocking for a “long time” to open the file.
>   This is only meaningful for some kinds of files, usually devices such
>   as serial ports; when it is not meaningful, it is harmless and
>   ignored.

Excerpt from https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open_002dtime-Flags.html.

So, the flag does not specify non-blocking *write*, but non-blocking *open*. The writing is still serial, and blocking, and slow.

Comment: Thank you very much. The notion of non-blocking is then related to reading from disk. Is that correct?

Comment: @SteveMcarthy It depends on the context being used. In this case, the flag is only in the context of opening files (and is considered only in a select few cases).

Comment: @SteveMcarthy Furthermore, you may want to consider that "asynchronous IO" and "non-blocking IO" don't mean the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/983764/4909087 for more.

Comment: I was told that write can be non-blocking as well so that is why I am trying this example! Thank you for clarifying

Comment: @SteveMcarthy I think it can (not sure), but certainly this flag is ignored for regular files, that I can guarantee.